# Pasar una cadena separada por comas como parámetro para una clausula IN

Tags: c#, oracle, dapper

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
select id from tabla where campo IN (:lista)
```

para una tabla formada basicamente por dos campos

| id | campo |
| --- | --- |
| numerico | varchar2 |

Para ejecutarla desde C# usando dapper, hago lo siguiente:

```csharp
db.QueryAsync<int>(@"
select id from tabla where campo IN (:lista)",
new
    {
        lista = LaLista
    }
)
```

donde LaLista es una cadena del tipo

```
Cadena1, cadena2, cadena3
```

Ahora, el problema es el siguiente. No importa como arme LaLista, Oracle entiende eso como un solo string. Probe armarla tambien de la siguiente forma

```
'Cadena1', 'cadena2', 'cadena3'
```

Pero el problema es el mismo. Como se le puede pasar una cadena a Oracle, para que la interprete dentro del IN como lo que es, varias variables, usando dapper?

P.D.:

En este caso, como LaLista es una cadena controlada por el sistema y no un input del usuario, se puede directamente concatenar dentro del query. Eso es lo que se hizo, pero me gustaria saber si existe una solucion sistemica.

Comment: ¿Y armarla como `'''Cadena1''', '''cadena2''', '''cadena3'''` (con triples comillas simples)? ¿Mismo problema?

Comment: Usar un arreglo??, usar el Split desde Oracle?

Comment: Revisa estas respuestas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58483450/how-to-pass-an-array-to-an-oracleparameter-for-in-condition

Comment: @javdromero eso es concatenar la cadena.. es lo que se hizo.. no aporta nada a esta pregunta ;)

Comment: @Japv lo podemos probar... que se te ocurre???

Comment: @padaleiana son muchas comillas simples.. ni se me ocurrio jajajaj ahi pruebo...

Comment: @gbianchi la idea mia es que la responsabilidad de separar la cadena en tokens lo haga Oracle y no c#

Comment: Y si hacemos new
    {
        lista = LaLista.Split(...)
    } @gbianchi

Comment: no hubo suerte con las mil comillas simples.. para mi, que oracle le pone comillas alrededor de lo que mande.. sea lo que sea... ahora paso el split.. no se si me va a dejar...

Comment: @Japv con el split tira el error de que falta el parentesis derecho... el tipico error que tira cuando no le gusta como se armo el query...

Comment: Yendo por las ramas: ¿`INSTR` no es opción?

Comment: @padaleiana ya lo encontre.. estoy usando mal dapper.. ahora en un rato pongo una respuesta...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El tema es que estaba usando mal dapper.

Dapper ya sabe que hacer con un iterable, por lo tanto, no es necesaria "construir" la cadena para la clausula IN.

Tambien, el sql esta incorrecto. Si bien es necesario poner entre parentesis todo lo que va al IN, en este caso, dapper y el motor se ocupan de eso por nosotros.

Por lo tanto, el codigo debe construirse de la siguiente forma:

```csharp
db.QueryAsync<int>(@"
select id from tabla where campo IN :lista",
new
    {
        lista = LaLista
    }
)
```

donde el objet LaLista no es mas un string concatenado (de ninguna forma) si no que es:

```csharp
IEnumerable<string> LaLista;
```

O cualquier tipo derivado del mismo.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar el tipo de parámetro `OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray` para enviar una lista.

```
List<string> myList = new List<string> { "item1", "item2", "item3" };

string sql = "select id from tabla where campo IN (:lista)";
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, connection);

// Añadir parámetro tipo lista
OracleParameter listParam = new OracleParameter();
listParam.ParameterName = "lista";
listParam.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
listParam.Value = myList.ToArray();
```

Comment: dapper... entendiste que es usando dapper? No esta mal, no es lo que estoy buscando...

Comment: Tu actitud y arrogancia es un desastre.

Comment: solo no entendiste la pregunta. es con dapper. no se porque lo ves mal, te estoy corrigiendo porque no es lo que estoy preguntando esto... No esta mal esta respuesta, no es la respuesta a esta pregunta solamente...